# 'What a big cheeks'? or 'What big cheeks'?

Tags: idioms, grammatical-number, indefinite-article

My brother just got his wisdom teeth extracted, and his cheeks are really big now. So cute.

I want to express my feeling by saying "What a big cheeks!"  But I feel weird about this sentence:  Because I am saying "cheeks" I should not use "a", but if I say "What big cheeks!" it feels even more weird…

Any suggestions?

Comment: "What big cheeks you have!" won't sound weird after you read the story of "Little Red Riding Hood".  This is a children's story that most native English speakers are familiar with.

Comment: quite similar: http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/17975/how-to-express-the-body-organs-in-pair-with-exclamation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What big cheeks!

This is correct.

Your reasoning is also correct: *cheeks* is plural so you don't use the indefinite article *a*.

Comment: If one cheek was swollen and the other looked normal, though, then you could say, "What a big cheek!"