# Is "What a big heart" structure valid when inserted within the speech?

Tags: sentence-construction, exclamatives

I read a similar question  which is ["What big cheeks!" and "What a big cheek!"](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/72162/what-a-big-cheeks-or-what-big-cheeks) (*I have rephrased the question according to the answer it received*).

As I, now, know that the phrasing is correct, I want to inquire about its validity when inserted within the speech as in the example:

> She can see **what** *a big heart* and *a charming personality* you have.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use expressions starting "what", "how", etc within sentences. A declaration may end with an exclamation mark, but this is usually omitted within a longer expression.

> What a pretty face you have!
>   I can see what a pretty face you have.
>
> How well you play the piano!
>   We can hear how well you play the piano.

With multiple items, the second and subsequent indefinite articles may be omitted:

> She can see what a big heart and charming personality you have. 
>   I can see what a big head, long neck, and small waist he has.